# ADT security system not responding after factory reset

Tags: security

I have an ADT Safewatch Pro 3000, and I recently reset it to factory settings (I went to the programming menu and typed *97). The screen displayed 97, but it wouldn't let me exit out of the programming menu with *99. After several minutes of this, I went and unplugged it. When I plugged it back in, it beeped, but the screen remained blank.

I'm not sure if I broke it, or something else happened. What can I do now? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Check with ADT, since they have to respond to alarms.

Comment: The service is disconnected, and I don't want the service. The system was installed when I moved in, and I was trying to get it to work with out service

Comment: It may have been shut from ADT itself.

Comment: No, that's not possible, I was just working on it minutes before this happened

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's possible (or even likely?) that the system was designed to fail if it has no service. Perhaps it worked for a while, but you hit a tripwire and now it's toast. Not much we can suggest from here: sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.

1. Unplug the power
2. Wait 1 minute
3. Plug it back in
4. Rush back to the panel within 30 seconds
5. Press and hold 1 and 3 until you see a number.
6. If the number is not 16, press 16*.

Do this quickly, because if you hesitate, it won't work and you'll have to try again.

Comment: Systems like this have configuration/programming modes that depend on sequences like you've found.   If you want to maintain the system yourself, try to find the Installation Manual that documents these things.   ADT considers this proprietary information, but you might find them through independent shops or DIY people on the net.  To prevent inadvertent calls to the monitoring station, disconnect the telephone connector.